# Freqeunt Failure Audit errors on web server (MSSQLSERVER)

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, logging, security

We have detected a lot of Failure Audit errors (MSSQLSERVER) on our Web Server for.

> Something like Login failed for user 'sa'. [CLIENT: 74.208.102.175]
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

IPs are unknown, and we would like to know is this a potential security issue or what can cause this.

**EDITED**

I adjusted Windows Firewall to prevent access to MSSQL outside server IP, but that did not work.

Here is what I did
Firewall > Programs and Service > cheched MSSQL
Firewall > Edit > Name:MSSQL, PortNumber 1433, TCP, scope: serverIP/255.255.255.255

Comment: Are the web and database server hosted on the same machine? What full version of sql server is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have exposed your SQL Server to the internet, and now you are seeing brute-force attempts from the internet to log in with the well-known SQL account sa.

I don't know your business needs, but consider adjusting your firewall so that the only IP that is able to reach your database server is your web server, for instance.

Edit: If your web server and your database server are the same, the fact remains that you need to use a firewall, either software or hardware, to block incoming connections to port 1433 from the internet.

Comment: It would also be wise to either disable or rename the SA account in SQL Server.

Comment: @Cougar9000 good alternative, but it would also open sql for outside connections

Comment: @Ryan Ries is there an option on SQL to close port 1433, or it can only be blocked on firewall?

Comment: @John This needs to be done via firewall. A hardware firewall is preferred, but in the meantime you could at least use the software firewall that comes with Server 2003... it sucks, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @RyanRies I have changed the firewall setting, and will monitor Event log.

Comment: @John it wasn't an alternative. It is an additional security best practice. If the app is not using the SA account, disable it and create an additional sysadmin account for internal use only

Comment: @RyanRies firwall solved the problem. So far..

Comment: @Cougar9000 I agree with you. But closing port 1433 for outside IP is still the best. Your suggestion is second best practice. Thanks

Comment: @John I know. The answer to the question was sufficient, so i added my two cents in the comments

Comment: @RyanRies it appears that modifyinig firewall settings did not solve the issue. I have edited my question